# iOS: Getting Apple ID From Bundle (Appirater)

Tags: ios, nsbundle, appirater

I'm using Appiraters code in order prompt users to rate the app after they've been using it for a while. (If your not familiar with it, here is a link:https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/)

It is running great, except for one small issue. I would like to use the exact same Appirater.h file in all of my projects, without having to change the code for each project. The only place in the code that is unique to the project is `APPIRATER_APP_ID 12345678`

The App_ID is not actually the App ID, it is the iTunes ID that is found in iTunes Connect. I was wondering if there is anyway that I can grab the ID out of the bundle and toss it into an NSString, so that I could just do `APPIRATER_APP_ID appIdFromString`, then not have to worry about having to change the code for each project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/pull/28) for that project that moves the App ID into Info.plist, and has the Appirater code pull the id from the plist. You could clone that contributor's fork to pickup the change, and you're good to go!

Comment: You're welcome! Lots of great stuff from talented folks on Github!